# Debug arrays in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

in Codeblocks I am trying to debug program

```
int main() {
fast;
vector<int> a;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) a.push_back(i);
for(int i=9; i>=0; i--) cout << a[i] << ' ';
cout << endl;
int b[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) b[i]=i;
for(int i=9; i>=0; i--) cout << b[i] << ' ';
}
```

So, when I turn on debug mode and debug it by clicking "Next line" I see that at the last line debugger goes to line in which the vector a is declared and doesn't print array b

So if i delete code about vector a, debugger just doesn't show array b.

How does this works?

Comment: i think you have to use "step over" instead of "step in"

Comment: Can't find button "step over" in debug panel

Comment: its shortcut is f5  or f6 or f7 i think; give it a try

Comment: f5 is a toggle breakpoint, f7 - next line

Answer (score 0):

Code::blocks provide the debugging feature. We can watch the values of variables and execute step by step.

Create the project
Add the break point by right click the mouse at the line number where you want and choose Toggle Break point.
Click on Debug menu and form debugging windows option select watches window.
In watches window you can see the values of variable and for step by step execution after break point use shift+F7 key.

My answer may not be clear for you or for further information you can follow this codeblocks wiki page http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Comment: I think it's better to use F7, because Shift+F7 will bring you to the giant code of modules STL C++.
I've already solved my problem, solution is above

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I forgot to remove line **fast;** from template, which worked as

```
#define fast cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);cin.sync_with_stdio(0);cout.sync_with_stdio(0);
```

This broke the output of the array in debug mode.

UPD by @N.Shead: You can also use `flush` or `endl` to print the buffer.

Comment: Just a thought, but you might also be able to get this to work even keeping your `fast` macro by adding `std::cout << std::flush` (or `std::endl`) after printing the array. This is because with your `fast` macro `std::cout` becomes buffered, and will not automatically write to the terminal unless its buffer either becomes full or you explicitly flush it. (Note that your program finishing also flushes the stream.)

Comment: @N.Shead yes, this helps too. I guessed before that `endl` affects the printing, now I'll also use `flush` :)

Comment: `std::cout << std::endl` is pretty much the same as `std::cout << '\n' << std::flush`; you don't need both! If you want the newline then `std::endl` is sufficient; if you don't want it then `std::flush` is correct. (Rereading your comment you might have understood that, but just making it clear)